# Anylogic getRemainingTime and Functions

Tags: timeout, queue, delay, anylogic, preemption

I am building a fairly simple model in Anylogic, and need to use the delay function 'getRemainingTime' and some functions in the 'queue' block: priority-based queueing, preemption and timeout. I have been unable to find a tutorial or examples online which talk about these. Could anyone please point out a resource or a built-in tutorial in Anylogic that covers things like this for beginner programmers like myself?
Thanks,
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation of the 'Delay' block here:
[AnyLogic Documentation: Delay Block](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FDelay.html)

The following built-in example models are adressing your topic. Access them in AnyLogic under Help/Example Models and then search for the names:

- Call Center
- Customer Support Center
- Interconnected Call Centers